# How to use EGOImageView with dynamic image sizes?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, egoimageview

I am using EGOImageView from Enormego (github [here](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)) and was wondering if anyone had successfully implemented this (along with the caching provided by EGOCache) with different size images. I can only get it to work with a static image size and it goes a bit haywire if I try to resize the image view after its finished loading or etc. Anyone got any ideas/bits of wisdom? I believe it's somewhere in the EGOImageLoader code but the blocks portion is a bit over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who might run across this problem, I modified the `imageLoaderDidLoad:` method of `EGOImageView` to this:

```
- (void)imageLoaderDidLoad:(NSNotification*)notification {
    UIImage* anImage = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"image"];
    if(anImage) {
        self.image = anImage;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height);
    } else {
        self.image = self.placeholderImage;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height);
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageViewLoadedImage:)]) {
        [self.delegate imageViewLoadedImage:self];
    }   
}
```

Comment: I actually modified the setImageURL: method and I put the self.frame properties and it works fine. Thanks !